# Convert text to image with both bold and normal text

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to convert a text string to an image in the following way:

> **Username:** ABC 123

basically I want "Username" to be bold and "ABC 123" to be normal.

Here is what I have done so far....I'm able to convert the text to image but Im only able to set the text as either all bold or all normal

```
private Stream CREATE_TEXT_IMAGE(string TEXTSTRING)
{
    string text = TEXTSTRING.Trim();
    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(1, 1);
    Font font = new Font("Calibri", 13, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    int width = System.Convert.ToInt32(graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Width);
    int height = System.Convert.ToInt32(graphics.MeasureString(text, font).Height);
    bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmap, new Size(width, height));
    graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);
    graphics.Flush();
    graphics.Dispose();
    Stream st = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(st, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return st;
}
```

Comment: You need to split the string and draw in two separate instructions with two different instances of two different Fonts. (One Bold, one Regular)

Comment: Please don't tag visual-studio unless your issue is specifically with Visual Studio. It shouldn't be used just because it's the IDE you're using.

Comment: BTW: What are you using the image for? Just display in the UI? In that case: why not create a custom component?

Comment: As Fildor said, since you can do all bold and all regular. You can split them, modify them and merge them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try a little something like this.

Note that I added some optimizations to reuse some objects. They might need to be disposed of when the containing class gets disposed. But like this you can get a little better on mem and time if this method is called frequently.

I also changed namings a little in direction of common C# guidelines.

```
private readonly Font _normFont = new Font("Calibri", 13, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
private readonly Font _boldFont = new Font("Calibri", 13, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
private readonly Graphics _measureGraphics = Graphics.FromBitmap(new BitMap(1,1));
private readonly SolidBrush _blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

private Stream CreateTextImage(string label, string text)
{
    // To simplify, we expect trimmed input.
    // string text = TEXTSTRING.Trim();

    // I always tend to add a little space between the text and the borders
    var marginHeight = 5.0; // I chose arbitrary values, you might want to
    var marginWidth  = 5.0; // pass these to the function ...

    var sizeLabel = _measureGraphics.MeasureString(label, _boldFont);
    var sizeText  = _measureGraphics.MeasureString(text, _normFont);

    var bitmap = new Bitmap(new Size(sizeLabel.Width + sizeText.Width + 2*marginWidth, 
                                     Math.Max(sizeLabel.Height, sizeText.Height) + 2*marginHeight));
    using var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
    graphics.Clear(Color.White);
    graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
    graphics.DrawString(label, _boldFont, _blackBrush, marginWidth, marginHeight);
    graphics.DrawString(text, _normFont, _blackBrush, sizeLabel.Width+marginWidth, marginHeight);
    graphics.Flush();
    Stream st = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    bitmap.Save(st, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return st;
}
```